# PHPMailer, Fatal Error when sending attached file

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm currently playing around in PHP and decided to try out PHPMailer. It worked smoothly until I added the option to attach files. I've been searching for posts with a similar problem but couldn't find anything so hopefully, someone on here can help me out.

So, when sending the mail I get an error message with the following:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_magic_quotes_runtime() in D:\xampp\htdocs\phpsandbox\PHPMailer_Test\class.phpmailer.php:2440 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\phpsandbox\PHPMailer_Test\class.phpmailer.php(2410): PHPMailer->encodeFile('D:\xampp\tmp\ph...', 'base64') #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\phpsandbox\PHPMailer_Test\class.phpmailer.php(2003): PHPMailer->attachAll('attachment', 'b1_8503701bcdda...') #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\phpsandbox\PHPMailer_Test\class.phpmailer.php(1110): PHPMailer->createBody() #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\phpsandbox\PHPMailer_Test\class.phpmailer.php(1069): PHPMailer->preSend() #4 D:\xampp\htdocs\phpsandbox\PHPMailer_Test\Test1.php(38): PHPMailer->send() #5 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\phpsandbox\PHPMailer_Test\class.phpmailer.php on line 2440

I've looked at the functions in the class itself, but I'm not getting any smarter by doing so. My PHP-file is pretty straight forward and if I comment out the line for adding attachments the mail is sent without issues.

My code:

```
    require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'mail@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = '******';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    
    
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->setFrom($_POST['from']);
    $mail->addAddress($_POST['to']);
    $mail->addCC($_POST['cc']);
    $mail->addBCC($_POST['bcc']);
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mail->Body = $_POST['message'];

    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file1']['name']);
    $mail->send();
```

I'm assuming there are some issues in my configuration?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using PHP 8? Because that function has been [removed](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-runtime).

Comment: You're right, I am! So the problem seems to be that I'm using an older version of PHPMailer. I tried downloading the current one but I'm getting an error when importing the class. "require 'PHPMailer.php' should be enough, right?

Comment: That's a different question then. If you try and can't make the new version work (make sure you do plenty of research), then post a new question about it. I'm not sure if that `require` is enough as I haven't used PHPMailer myself.

Comment: Did you use v5 before? Things have changed a lot in v6, you need to explicitly include the necessary classes now, see https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#installation--loading (or use composer, then you can make use of the autoload functionality.)

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciate it! I'll try the newest version, should solve the issue.

@CBroe No, I've used v8 all along. However, I found an old forum post regarding PHPMailer with a good explanation of how to use it containing a Zip-file with the older version of PHPMailer. In hindsight, I should've gone directly to the GitHub.

Comment: I was talking about the PHPMailer version (the latest is 6),. not the PHP version.

Comment: PHPMailer has a ton of documentation and examples you should be starting with, including [this one](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) which does exactly what you're asking, but safely, and with error checking :). You are indeed using an ancient version, and you should definitely learn to use composer, even for a single package import.